# I want to calculate the score of the characters in a sentence

Tags: php, regex

I have a sentence as an input.
I want to be able to calculate the total score of a sentence `(a=1, b=2, c=3)`, according to the letters that form each word.

Also, if a sentence has a double letter `i` want to double its value.

Finally, I want to filter out characters different from a-z.

Code (Edited)

```
$words = "Try to do this";  
$letters = str_split($words);  
$value = '0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s  u v w x y z';  
$value = explode(' ',$value);  
$value1 = array_flip($value); 
$result = array_intersect($letters, $value);
```

This is something I started but can't finish and I post it just to see if my logic is correct!

Comment: Walking the array and passing each character to the ord() function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) might be a good place to start.  Subtract 96 from the ord() return value to get a = 1, b = 2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your code & think this will work as expected. I have edited this code so it can now account for double score items properly. Note that the `$double_score_array` has only single letters, but the regex has `{2}` to indicate that 2 letters in a row should be looked at. Comments are in place to explain each stage:

```
// Set the '$words' string.
$words = "Try to do thiis.";

// Set an array for double score items.
$double_score_array = array('i');

// Init the '$raw_results' array
$raw_results = array();    

// Create a '$value_array' using the range of 'a' to 'z'
$value_array = range('a','z');

// Prepend a '0' onto the '$value_array'
array_unshift($value_array, 0);

// Flip the '$value_array' so the index/key values can be used for scores.
$value_array_flipped = array_flip($value_array); 

// Filter out any character that is not alphabetical.
$words = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', strtolower($words));

// Let's roll through the double score items.
foreach ($double_score_array as $double_score_letter) {
  preg_match('/' . $double_score_letter . '{2}/', $words, $matches);
  $double_score_count = count($matches);

  // With double score items accounted, let's get rid of the double score item to get normal scores.
  $words = preg_replace('/' . $double_score_letter . '{2}/', '', $words);
}

// Split the '$words' string into a '$letters_array'
$letters_array = str_split($words);

// Now let's set the value for the double score items.
$raw_results[] = (($value_array_flipped[$double_score_letter] * 2) * $double_score_count);

// Roll through the '$letters_array' and assign values.
foreach ($letters_array as $letter_key => $letter_value) {
  $raw_results[] = $value_array_flipped[$letter_value];
}

// Filter out the empty values from '$raw_results'.
$filtered_results = array_filter($raw_results);

// Run an 'array_sum()' on the '$filtered_results' to get a final score.
$final_results = array_sum($filtered_results);

// Echo the score value in '$final_results'
echo 'Score: ' . $final_results;

// Dump the '$filtered_results' for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($filtered_results);
echo '</pre>';
```

**EDIT** In the comments the original poster states that the code above does not double the score. Unclear about that since—as per the example—the letter `i` is the 9th letter of the alphabet.  So the score would be 9. So wouldn’t double score be `18`? Or so you mean it should be `36` meaning double the score of the two individual `i` items?

If “double score” actually means taking the score of the two individual items & doubling it, then simply go to this portion of the code:

```
// Now let's set the value for the double score items.
$raw_results[] = (($value_array_flipped[$double_score_letter] * 2) * $double_score_count);
```

And change the `2` to `4` like so to effectively double the score of double letter ietms:

```
// Now let's set the value for the double score items.
$raw_results[] = (($value_array_flipped[$double_score_letter] * 4) * $double_score_count);
```

**ANOTHER EDIT** Okay, I think I understand the original posters request. Specifically when they ask, “Also, if a sentence has a double letter i want to double its value.” Which I—and others interpreted as two letters in a row such as `ii`, but seems that if those two letters show up in a sentence only *then* would the score be doubled. So I reworked the logic to account for any two instances of `i` showing up in a sentence.  And since it’s unclear what should happen if more than 2 `i`’s show up in a sentence, I set logic to account for cases like that; those extra `i`’s just get a single value. Adding my new version. Compare & contrast with the first version above. You should now be able to do whatever you need to.

```
// Set the '$words' string.
$words = "Try to do thiiis.";

// Set an array for double score items.
$double_score_array = array('i');

// Set a double score multiplier.
$double_score_multiplier = 2;

// Init the '$raw_results' array
$raw_results = array();    

// Create a '$value_array' using the range of 'a' to 'z'
$value_array = range('a','z');

// Prepend a '0' onto the '$value_array'
array_unshift($value_array, 0);

// Flip the '$value_array' so the index/key values can be used for scores.
$value_array_flipped = array_flip($value_array); 

// Filter out any character that is not alphabetical.
$words = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', strtolower($words));

// Let's roll through the double score items.
$double_score_count = $non_double_count = 0;
foreach ($double_score_array as $double_score_letter) {
  $double_score_regex = sprintf('/%s{1}/', $double_score_letter);
  preg_match_all($double_score_regex, $words, $matches);
  $count = count($matches[0]);

  // We only want to double the score for the first two letters found.
  if ($count >= 2) {
    $double_score_count = 2;
  }

  // This handles the accounting for items past the first two letters found.
  $non_double_count += ($count - 2);

  // This handles the accounting for single items less than the first two letters found.
  if ($count < 2) {
    $non_double_count += $count;
  }

  // With double score items accounted, let's get rid of the double score item to get normal scores.
  $words = preg_replace($double_score_regex, '', $words);
}

// Split the '$words' string into a '$letters_array'
$letters_array = str_split($words);

// Now let's set the value for the double score items.
if ($double_score_count > 0) {
  $raw_results[] = (($value_array_flipped[$double_score_letter] * $double_score_multiplier) * $double_score_count);
}

// And get the values of items that are non-double value.
if ($non_double_count > 0) {
  $raw_results[] = $value_array_flipped[$double_score_letter] * $non_double_count;
}

// Roll through the '$letters_array' and assign values.
foreach ($letters_array as $letter_key => $letter_value) {
  $raw_results[] = $value_array_flipped[$letter_value];
}

// Filter out the empty values from '$raw_results'.
$filtered_results = array_filter($raw_results);

// Run an 'array_sum()' on the '$filtered_results' to get a final score.
$final_results = array_sum($filtered_results);

// Echo the score value in '$final_results'
echo 'Score: ' . $final_results;

// Dump the '$filtered_results' for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($filtered_results);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Input string
$str = 'Try to do this';

// Remove irrelevant characters, convert to lowercase
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', strtolower($str));

// Create a function to determine the value of a character
function my_char_value($char) {
    return ord($char) - 96;
}

// Convert the string to an array and apply our function to each element
$arr = array_map('my_char_value', str_split($str));

// Add each array element to determine subtotal
$sum = array_sum($arr);

// Double the sum if two "i"s are present in the string
if (preg_match('/i.*?i/', $str)) {
    $sum *= 2;
}

print $sum;
```

Comment: Works great. thank you! The problem is tha it doesn't double the score! If you have an input "aa" it should give as a score not 2!it only works for "i's". Do you know how to make it for char (a-z)?despite putting 26 if?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function counter($string) {
    // count the number of times each letter occurs, filtering out anything other than a-z
    $counts = array_count_values(
        str_split(
            preg_replace('/[^a-z]/iS', '', strtolower($string))
        )
    );

    // convert the counts to Caeser ciphers (a => 1, aa => 2, bb => 4, etc.)
    array_walk(
        $counts,
        function (&$value, $letter) {
            $value = $value * (ord($letter) - 96);
        }
    );

    // sum up the encodings
    $sum = array_sum($counts);

    // if there's a double i, double again
    if (preg_match('/ii/iS', $string)) {
        $sum *= 2;
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

**Test cases**

```
echo counter("i"); // = 9
echo counter("ii"); // = 36
echo counter("abc0"); // = 6
echo counter("aabc0"); // = 7
echo counter("aabbcc00"); // = 12
echo counter("Try to do this"); // = 173
```

Comment: very nice code, but it doubles only in case there are two i's next to each other and not if two letters appear in the same sentence

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not 100% sure I understand your requirements. The accepted answer also does `preg_match('/ii/')` (using the loop and the {2}), yes?  I've edited my response with test cases -- is one of those wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a better solution
Check this code out

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Script to calculate the total score of a sentence (a=1, b=2, c=3), according to the letters that form each word. 
    * Also, if a sentence has a double letter i want to double its value.
    * Finally, I want to filter out characters different from a-z. 
    * 
    * Author: Viswanath Polaki
    * Created: 5-12-2013 
    */

    //array to define weights
    $weight = array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3,
        'd' => 4,
        'e' => 5,
        'f' => 6,
        'g' => 7,
        'h' => 8,
        'i' => 9,
        'j' => 10,
        'k' => 11,
        'l' => 12,
        'm' => 13,
        'n' => 14,
        'o' => 15,
        'p' => 16,
        'q' => 17,
        'r' => 18,
        's' => 19,
        't' => 20,
        'u' => 21,
        'v' => 22,
        'w' => 23,
        'x' => 24,
        'y' => 25,
        'z' => 26
    );
    //your sentance
    $sentance = "My name is Viswanath Polaki. And my lucky number is 33";
    $asentance = array();
    $strlen = strlen($sentance);
    //converting sentance to array and removing spaces
    for ($i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++) {
      if ($sentance[$i] != " ")
        $asentance[] = strtolower($sentance[$i]);
    }
    $sumweights = array();
    //calculation of weights
    foreach ($asentance as $val) {
      if (key_exists($val, $weight)) {
        $sumweights[$val] += $weight[$val];
      } else {
        $sumweights['_unknown'][] = $val;
      }
    }
    ksort($sumweights);//sorting result
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($sumweights);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```